# autoresize text in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In the process of studying QML and QtQuick, the following question arose. How can I make the text automatically reduce the font size by decreasing the element in which it is located. 
Now I have this method

```
Rectangle {
id: main_window
width: 700
height: 500

property int main_w: main_window.width

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: 'green'

    Text {
        text: "SIZE ME!!!"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: 'white'
        font.pointSize: {
            if (main_window.main_w < main_window.width)
                return main_window.main_w / 35 // we need 20pt
            return main_window.width / 35
        }
        visible: {
            if (parent.width < 100)
                return false
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but not too elegantly. Maybe there are some methods that the text automatically resized. If the wrap in the `ColumnLayout` does not work.

Please help. Thank you

Here my code with `fontSizeMode` trying:

```
Rectangle {
id: root
width: 700
height: 700
property int mrg: 10   

Rectangle {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: 'green'

    Text {
        id: field
        text: "Size me!"
        minimumPointSize: 10
        font.pointSize: 60
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        color: 'white'
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Text elements `fontSizeMode` property to set autosizing (`Text.HorizontalFit`, `Text.VerticalFit` or `Text.Fit`).
You can adjust the minimum font size with `minimumPixelSize` property.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#fontSizeMode-prop for details

Comment: I looked at these methods, but for some reason, there is no effect

Comment: @v_sith_v: Could you edit your question, to include your try with the `fontSizeMode`-property?

Comment: I figured out this problem. Your advice was right. Thank you

Comment: Two more things: font.pointSize (or font.pixelSize) is in fact the maximum size. The font will not fit over this value. For very high definition, put a big value. The second thing is: in the form editor the maximum value allowed for the font size is 400. For bigger value you will have to use the text editor

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too, but figured, that you need only set the width and height of the Text item relative to the item/object where you want the text fitted (parent). Here is a working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 700
    height: 700
    property int mrg: 10   

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: root.width * 0.5
        height: root.height * 0.5
        color: 'green'

        Text {
            id: field
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            text: "Size me!"
            minimumPointSize: 10
            font.pointSize: 60
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            color: 'white'
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If the rect is very small, text could be hanging out because of the minimumPointSize: 10.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the above answers is that if you have a reusable font that you share across your app if you set `font.pixel/pointSize` it will be changed everywhere which is not wanted to solve that you can create a new font like this:

```
import QtQuick 

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 700
    height: 700
    property int mrg: 10   

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: root.width * 0.5
        height: root.height * 0.5
        color: 'green'

        Text {
            id: field
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            text: "Size me!"
            color: 'white'
            font: Qt.font({
                        bold: true,
                        underline: false,
                        pixelSize: field.width / 10, // resize relative to parent
                        family: Theme.fFamily,
                })
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```